# Connecting RFM12B transmitter to Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino

I need to connect RFM12B radio transmitter to my Arduino Leonardo. I've found a [library](https://jeelabs.org/2009/02/10/rfm12b-library-for-arduino/), but I'm not sure about the pinouts. Also I've noticed that this module should get 3.3V. Of course there is 3.3V pin for VCC, but digital outputs also has to be 3.3V. Can I use for this purpose simple resistor divider?

Answer (score 0):

It would not be a good idea to use a resistor divider to supply 3.3V. A resistor divider should only be used as a voltage *reference*, meaning that you shouldn't try to power anything from it.

The RFM12B uses SPI to communicate with your MCU. It looks like the library that you linked has provisions for the ATmega32u4. Assuming that's the MCU that you're working with, you should be good to go. If you're unsure about which pins to connect to your MCU, I would recommend reading through the library, and checking which pins it's setting up for SPI communication. It's a good idea to make sure that your library is doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this. I think that's how I should connect it.

```
#define RFM_IRQ     0    //PD0, INT0, Digital3 
#define SS_DDR      DDRB
#define SS_PORT     PORTB
#define SS_BIT      6    //Dig10, PB6


#define SPI_SS      17     // PB0, pin 8, Digital17
#define SPI_MISO    14     // PB3, pin 11, Digital14
#define SPI_MOSI    16     // PB2, pin 10, Digital16
#define SPI_SCK     15     // PB1, pin 9, Digital15
```

I'm trying to control my window blinds using arduino. I want to 'read' what my [remote controller](https://mobilus.pl/files/instrukcje/mobilus_cosmo_hm3plus_instr_s_eng.pdf) sends and duplicate that signal. But I'm not sure if it would work...

Comment: If that's under the section for your MCU, then yes.

Comment: @DanielGiesbrecht nex thing - this remote controller has `dynamic code`. So is it even possible to read that data and replicate it using this module?

Comment: I don't think I can answer that in a comment. I'd add it (in detail) to this or a new question.

Comment: So I'd be grateful if you could answer this in the "answer" ;)

Comment: I'm saying that you need to provide more information to your question first.

Comment: What would you want to know?